# Are Python class variables initialized before initialization of first class instance?

Tags: python

I don't yet know how to find information in the Python docs when I need it. I would appreciate it if someone could point me to the section that addresses class variable initialization. **I would like to know when class variables are initialized.**

This is of interest to me because I have written a class that holds a single database connection in a class variable, so I would like to ensure that this connection is not opened until the first class instance is created.

I realize I could do this by initially setting the connection to None and then initializing it when the first instance is initialized, in its **init** method, but this seems more complicated than it should be. Am I safe with the following:

```
class DatabaseConnection:   
    connection = DB_API.makeConnection()
    ...
```

Comment: The class body gets executed when the class is _defined_ so the connection will be created as soon as you import the module containing that class.

Comment: @tzaman thanks. mind telling me how you know this?

Comment: The [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) is useful. You could also just try putting a `print` there and see what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) for class definitions says, as one of the steps in executing the class definition:

> The class’s suite is then executed

(A "suite" is a code block, i.e., the body of the class definition.)

So the class body is executed right away when the class is defined.